# Remove committed git folder from repo but not from local

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I committed test-output by mistake, tried to remove the folder using the below command in my git bash[Master]

```
$ git rm -r --cached test-output
```

It says it removed all the content, but in my git repo I still see the folder with all the files

Comment: You also need to commit.

Comment: And push it up to the repo

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
  git rm --cached -r app/widgets/yourfolder/
```

Then run   [git -clean](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)   to remove untracked files from the working Directory

```
  git clean -f {dir_path}
```

Finally check if the untracked files are gone. with [git -status](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status)

```
 git status
```